# What is our stance on questions about processing times of immigration procedures?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about processing times of immigration procedures? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

Based on our [what topics can I ask here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> If your question is about:
>
> (...)
>
> Questions about work, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country for more time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow
>
> (...)
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I believe processing times for these kind of visas are an important part of the application process. Whether they are answerable is another questions though. In some cases there are official guidelines on the processing time requirements, but usually there are only anecdotal information about the processing times. These are still okay as answers, but they clearly have to state that they are in no way official estimates, and it might differ for your case.

Note however that the question needs to be about processing times for long term visas, unless the short term visa is part of the process of obtaining a long term visa (usually from within the country)